# Disadvantages of using large variables/arrays on the stack?

Tags: c++, performance, stack

What are the disadvantages, if any, of defining large arrays or objects on the stack? Take the following example:

```
int doStuff() {
   int poolOfObjects[1500];
   // do stuff with the pool
   return 0;
}
```

Are there any performance issues with this? I've heard of stack overflow issues, but I'm assuming that this array isn't big enough for that.

Comment: Btw, a fairly common cause of stack overflow is that someone takes some code in which "the array isn't big enough for that", and tries to use it on a system with much smaller stack. So if you do nothing else, you'll be doing them a favour by documenting which functions are stack-hungry, just to save them a bit of time when porting. Of course if your code is desktop or server only, forever, then there's no issue, but it's worth being very conservative in libraries, since if a library is any good then it's worth porting :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stack overflow is a problem, if

- the array is larger than the thread stack
- the call tree is very deep, or
- the function uses recursion

In all other cases, stack allocation is a very fast and efficient way to get memory.  Calling a large number of constructors and destructors can be slow, however, so if your constructor/destructor are non-trivial, you might want to look at a longer-lived pool.

Comment: But please note, stackoverflow.com is *NEVER* a problem.

Answer (score 5):

As you have mentioned, **overrunning the stack is the primary issue**. Even if your particular case isn't very large, consider what will happen if the function is recursive.

Even worse, **if the function is called from a recursive function, it may be inlined** - thus leading to "surprise" stackoverflow problems. (I've run into this issue multiple times with the Intel Compiler.)

---

As far as performance issues go, these are better measured than guessed. But having a very large array on the stack could potentially hurt data-locality if it separates other variables.

Other than that, stack allocation is dirt-cheap and faster than heap allocation. On some compilers (like MSVC), using more than 4k stack will make the compiler generate a buffer security check. (But it can be disabled though.)

Comment: Yeah... I had a case where a logarithmic-depth recursive function called a 2k-stack function 10 times. (ICC inlined all 10 calls!) Since it was logarithmic depth with the input size, it would only crash when the datasize was > 2TB and the repro-time was 7 days... It took 4 weeks for me to trace it down to the inlining leading to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/kennethlaskoski/SubtleBug

This code contains a bug that I call subtle because the binary runs flawlessly on iOS Simulator and crashes shamefully on a real device.
Spoiler ahead: what happens on a real device is a classic *stack overflow* due to allocation of a very large variable.
The simulator uses the much larger x86 stack, so all goes well.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_large_stack_variables

Answer (score 0):

The stack overflow issues should be your main technical concern, but if this code is going to be used by others its careful to consider if the magic size of 1500 might disrupt someone's usage of this function.