# C - Can't store file into an array of strings (based off line break)

Tags: c

I'm pretty new to C and someone "challenged" me to try and create a sorting program using C. I come from languages that are higher-level where doing something like this is easier, but I guess the lower-level intricacies are way over my head. I haven't implemented the sorting yet, because I've ran across an obstacle (just one of many) along the way.

Anyways, here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *unsortedFile; /* prepare file variable */
    char lineBuffer[100]; /* prepare variable for each line */
    char *listOfLines[100]; /* prepare line array variable to be sorted */
    int n = 0; 
    int i;
    if (argc == 2) /* if a file has been given */
    {
        unsortedFile = fopen(argv[1], "r"); /* open it readonly */
        if (unsortedFile == NULL) /* if it couldn't open */
        {
            printf("Couldn't open the file %s\n", argv[1]);
            printf("Does it exist?\n");
            return -1; /* stop the program here, return non-zero for error */
        }
        printf("original file:\n\n");
        while (fgets(lineBuffer, sizeof(lineBuffer), unsortedFile))
        {
            printf("%s", lineBuffer);
            listOfLines[n] = lineBuffer; /* store line buffer to the array */
            n = ++n; /* increase n for the next array element */
        }
        printf("\nLines to be sorted: %d\n", n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("%s", listOfLines[i]);
        }
    } else /* if no or too many args provided */
    {
        printf("\nArgument error - you either didn't supply a filename\n");
        printf("or didn't surround the filename in quotes if it has spaces\n\n");
        return -1; /* return non-zero for error */
    }
}
```

At this point, you're probably busy vomiting over the messiest spaghetti code you've ever seen... but anyways, the issue occurs with that `while` statement, I guess. The original file prints to the console fine, but I don't think each line is being stored to `listOfLines`.

Here is what's in `file.txt`, the file I am supplying as an argument to the program:

```
zebra
red
abacus
banana
```

And here is the output of the program:

```
dustin@DESKTOP-033UL9B:/mnt/c/Users/Dustin/projects/c/sort$ ./sort file.txt
original file:

zebra
red
abacus
banana

Lines to be sorted: 4
banana
banana
banana
banana
dustin@DESKTOP-033UL9B:/mnt/c/Users/Dustin/projects/c/sort$
```

Looks like the last line of the file is the only one being stored to `listOfLines`? What could cause this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `getline` instead of `fgets`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Are you sure OPs platform has it? Looks like MinGW, so maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need an array of char arrays (not array of pointers)

Switched:

```
char *lineOfLines[100];      // array of pointers
char listOfLines[100][100];  // array of char arrays
```

2. Then use `strcpy`.

Switched:

```
listOfLines[n] = lineBuffer;
strcpy(listOfLines[n], lineBuffer);
```

Working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *unsortedFile; /* prepare file variable */
    char lineBuffer[100]; /* prepare variable for each line */
    char listOfLines[100][100]; /* prepare line array variable to be sorted */
    int n = 0; 
    int i;
    if (argc == 2) /* if a file has been given */
    {
        unsortedFile = fopen(argv[1], "r"); /* open it readonly */
        if (unsortedFile == NULL) /* if it couldn't open */
        {
            printf("Couldn't open the file %s\n", argv[1]);
            printf("Does it exist?\n");
            return -1; /* stop the program here, return non-zero for error */
        }
        printf("original file:\n\n");
        while (fgets(lineBuffer, sizeof(lineBuffer), unsortedFile))
        {
            printf("%s", lineBuffer);
            strcpy(listOfLines[n], lineBuffer); /* store line buffer to the array */
            n = n + 1; /* increase n for the next array element */
        }
        printf("\nLines to be sorted: %d\n", n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("%s", listOfLines[i]);
        }
    } else /* if no or too many args provided */
    {
        printf("\nArgument error - you either didn't supply a filename\n");
        printf("or didn't surround the filename in quotes if it has spaces\n\n");
        return -1; /* return non-zero for error */
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should warn the OP about not use the stack too much. It's could stack overflow :p. By the way return -1 is not valid in main

Comment: I am not very experienced with C, just at troubleshooting. I am respectfully asking for you to explain to me what you mean? Or point me in the direction of some good articles about it? I understand what a StackOverflow is, but I am not experienced enough to see the issue with the code as it is. :)

Comment: return value of main are ["between 0 and 255"](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html#Exit-Status). And there link will explain you the stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072415/disadvantages-of-using-large-variables-arrays-on-the-stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158/how-does-a-stack-overflow-occur-and-how-do-you-prevent-it

Comment: Well, this is only about 10k of stack. I've used several megabytes of stack before and it worked fine on Linux.

Comment: @Stargateur Your "between 0 and 255" reference is only for glibc, not C in general (but the only portable exit codes in standard C are 0, `EXIT_SUCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`, which is even more restrictive).

Comment: I will change the return codes to something else besides negative one; thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @melpomene If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int , a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned  by  the main function  as  its  argument; 11) reaching  the } that  terminates  the main function returns  a  value  of  0.  If  the  return  type  is  not  compatible  with int, the
termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf

Comment: @melpomene So the more portable way is to only use MACRO EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE or 0, 1. In my opinion of course.

Comment: I read the StackOverflow article linked by Stargateur. Am I to gather that, in C, a pointer puts things on "the heap" and that using that char array puts things on "the stack," i.e., a pointer can't overwrite function code but a char array can?

Comment: @varlogtim I know that linux have protection to avoid this. Some hacker exploits this before. I can't answer you more. But yes in some case it's possible. But all modern OS avoids this. You need to deactivate manually there protection.

Comment: @varlogtim It's not about pointers vs. arrays, it's that local variables are generally placed on "the stack" whereas memory allocated with `malloc` comes from "the heap". (Declaring a pointer only creates that pointer; you can make it point to wherever you want.)

Answer (score 3):

`listOfLines` is an array of pointers. All those pointers are set to point to `lineBuffer`:

```
     listOfLines[n] = lineBuffer;
```

And `lineBuffer` is repeatedly overwritten by lines from the file. The last line is `banana`, which is the final value of `lineBuffer`.

Your code then prints the values in `listOfLines`, which are all pointers to `lineBuffer`.

---

This line is very wrong, by the way (it has undefined behavior):

```
    n = ++n;
```

If you want to increment `n`, that's either

```
n = n + 1;
```

or

```
++n;
```

Basically, don't modify the same variable twice within the same statement.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!